# Match HTML Elements

Tags: php

How do I create a regular expression, that will match only the following

```
<div>some text</div>
<div class="someclass">some more content text</div>
```

Comment: do you need to get the content on every `div`?

Comment: yes, my aim is to put this into a variable, so it can be used for other tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern='/\<div.*?\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/';
$count=preg_match($pattern,$string1,$matches);
```

- $matches[0] will have the matches including the div tags (=outerHTML)
- $matches[1] will have the matches excluding the div tags (=innerHTML)

Use `preg_match_all()` if you want to match all divs in a HTML sniplet.

Comment: This isn't what I need. This won't match the <div class="someclass">some more content text</div>